# "Find Handle or DLL" from "Process Explorer" not searching System's "dll"s?

Tags: windows, drivers, process-explorer

"Process Explorer" is the TOOL for Windows, one use for me is too see system drivers, that's watching DLLs in the process "System" (Pid 4 - always?). The drivers aren't, of course, DLLs, BUT for the system they are some kind of drivers (kernel extensions), that's why probably they are show there. My question - why the search ("Find Handle or DLL") doesn't work for them?

Windows 7, Process Explorer v15.12

Comment: seems to be PID of 4 on my comp and if I right click the system process and click properties, then threads, i see some files. like testing on xp, i see some sys files and ntoskernel.exe or something like that.. don't see any dlls at the moment there but i'm over vnc and things a bit sluggish.. but it may be there are no dlls that it uses in which case that could explain it

Comment: on both win7 and win xp. system idle has(or is shown to have) pid 0 and system has pid 4.

Comment: No right click: Ctrl-L (View/Show lower pane), Ctrl-H (View/Lower pane view) to switch between DLLs and Handles

Comment: Asking "Why?" here would probably need someone who has the source code. You could try to write Mark Russinovich an Email instead.

Comment: What is your search term? It seems to work for me with Process Explorer 15.40

Comment: At work I have `Xp` and `15.40`: it still doesn't work, tried to search "BEEP" (from "BEEP.sys").

Comment: Or "hal.dll", eveybody has one ;)

Answer (score 2):

For information, a .sys "driver" is nothing else but a renamed .dll.

I suppose that Process Explorer has a problem with the System process
because this is a very special process with unique permission.
Feel free to complain about this inefficiency on their [forum](http://forum.sysinternals.com/).

If you are looking for an immediate solution, you could use [Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/).
This is an open-source alternative process viewer with roughly the same capabilities
as Process Explorer, except it does not have a dual-pane display.

I have tested searching for a DLL used by the System process, and Process Hacker
did find it.

Comment: `Process Explorer` doesn't have a problem with `System` process since it shows all the loaded drivers in the lower pane (when selected). Why does not find them? For instace, I see `Beep.sys` there, why is not found? It has a name, it has a path, it should be found.

Comment: Yes, it should. This is maybe caused by the code that lists the DLLs not using the same system calls as the one that does the search. This is why I feel that you should report it as a bug. With the rate at which arrive new releases of Process Explorer, you have a good chance of a speedy solution.

Comment: Nice explanation, but it seems so hard to report the bug on their site. I have to ... complete a form to register D:<, I never do that!

Comment: I know the guy behind `Process Explorer` for some years and I presume all the work behind it, why should I trust this `Process Hacker` of yours? Is it made by Steve Balmer, Jeffrey Richter, Jeff Atwood or Raymond Chen?

Comment: I normally use Process Explorer but I also have Process Hacker and I use it when PE fails. PH is open-source and is distributed by all the major download sites, including PortableApps, Softpedia, Cnet and Majorgeeks, so it should be safe.

Comment: It's not about safety that I am worried, but about its performances.

Comment: If start-time is the question, I find that for me PH starts much faster than PE. For the rest, only experimentation can tell. Can't be too bad with user rating on sourceforge at 4.7 out of 5 and glowing reviews.